# Delaying a running bash command

Tags: linux, bash, loops, delay, sleep

I'm trying to delay a php command by inserting it into a bash script that pauses and resumes the command without stopping/starting it again. I need the command to run for about 10sec then sleep for 5sec forever until the command has completed (will take all night)
Example:

```
#!/bin/bash
php /my/command/here & sleep 5 & resume/my/command
```

Im no bash expert but im sure theres a "while" command that could be used here somewhere.

Comment: What does pausing and resuming mean in this context? "then sleep for 5secs forever" is a contradiction in terms. Do you mean a loop in which you sleep for 5 seconds, then check a condition, then sleep again?

Comment: Can you provide us with a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? Your question as it stands is unclear, but a bit of *actual* code should clear things up nicely.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following approach commented in the script below:

```
#!/bin/bash
php /my/command/here & #run your command in background 
P="$!" # keep the pid of your command
sleep 10
kill -TSTP "$P" # send signal to suspend your command
sleep 5
fg "$P" # resume command
```

Answer (score 0):

Run the `php` command in the background, then run a loop that continually sends `SIGSTOP` and `SIGCONT` to the process.

Use two background processes, one to run `php` and the other to run a script that repeatedly pauses and resumes the `php` script. (The `sleep`s run in the background so that the pauser can be interrupted as soon as `php` completes). Once the two background jobs are started, we just wait for `php` to complete, then kill anything still running in the background.

```
php /my/command/here & php_id=$!

while :; do
    sleep 10 & wait
    kill -s STOP "$php_id"
    sleep 5 & wait
    kill -s CONT "$php_id"
done &

wait "$php_id"
kill $(jobs -p)
```